# Invoke-Command vs PSExec on a remote script, different process names executed and not working?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run a script on remote machines using two methods. One is using Invoke-Command with the PS1 file already in a temp folder. And the other is PSEXEC. Right now only PSEXEC seem to work.

**Method 1 Using Invoke-Command on local copy of .ps1**

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName PC1 -FilePath "C:\Windows\Temp\LaunchWindowsUpdateAssistance.ps1"
```

**Method 2 Using PSEXEC**

```
$ps1 = "\\UNC\PATH\LaunchWindowsUpdateAssistance.ps1"

& "C:\Windows\System32\psexec.exe" -u domain\user.name -p passwordhere -h \\PC1 Powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -File $ps1
```

**The PS1 being executed**

```
$logs = "C:\Windows\Temp\logs"
$msbuild = "C:\windows\temp\Windows10Upgrade9252(21H2).exe"
$Args = "/quietinstall /skipeula /auto upgrade /copylogs $($logs)"
Start-Process -FilePath $msbuild -ArgumentList $args -Wait -PassThru
```

**Problem**

Method 1 Process name = Windows10UpgraderApp (This is what Windows gave it, THIS FAILS AFTER 10 MINUTES)

Method 2 Process name = Windows10Upgrade9252(21H2) (This is the exact name of the .exe I specified, and it works)

Comment: Just to ensure you're aware, the temp ps1 youre calling from `Invoke-Command` has to be on your computer.

Comment: Please Verify your log files for the reason of failing.